# Pure CSS onclick event checkbox hack problem

Tags: html, css

So i have a robot drawn in HTML+CSS, colored via "background-color" and i want his parts to change color onclick. I know it can be done(probably) in several easy quick lines of JS\Jquery, but i want a pure CSS solution.
I've been trying to implement the checkbox hack, but failed miserably(see "#recolor:checked > .torso" section in CSS part).
Code included.

```css
body{
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.788);
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 margin-left: 50px;
 color: whitesmoke;
}

.robots {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 margin-left: 100px;
}

nav{
 position: fixed;
 top: 75px;
 left: 20px;
 margin: 0px 50px 0px 20px;
        width: 300px;
 color: blanchedalmond;
}

ul{
 list-style: none;
}

.head, 
.left_arm, 
.torso, 
.right_arm, 
.left_leg, 
.right_leg {
 background-color: #5f93e8;
}

#recolor:checked > .torso {
 background-color: chartreuse;
}


.head { 
 width: 200px; 
 margin: 0 auto; 
 height: 150px; 
 border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0; 
 margin-bottom: 10px;
} 

.eyes {
 display:flex;
}

.head:hover {
 width: 300px;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}


.upper_body { 
 width: 300px; 
 height: 150px;
 display: flex; 
} 

.left_arm, .right_arm { 
 width: 40px; 
 height: 125px;
 border-radius: 100px; 
} 

.left_arm { 
 margin-right: 10px; 
} 

.left_arm:hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
    transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.right_arm { 
 margin-left: 10px; 
} 

.torso { 
 width: 200px; 
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px; 
} 

.lower_body { 
 width: 200px; 
 height: 200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: flex;
} 

.left_leg, .right_leg { 
 width: 40px; 
 height: 120px;
 border-radius: 0 0 100px 100px;  
} 

.left_leg { 
 margin-left: 45px; 
} 

.left_leg:hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
 transform: rotate(20deg);
}

.right_leg:hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg);
 transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.right_leg { 
 margin-left: 30px; 
}

.left_eye, .right_eye { 
 width: 20px; 
 height: 20px; 
 border-radius: 15px; 
 background-color: white;  
} 

.left_eye { 
 position: relative; 
 top: 100px; 
 left: 40px; 
} 

.right_eye { 
 position: relative; 
 top: 100px; 
 left: 120px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>RoboPage</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
 <h1>Robot Friend</h1>
 </header>
 <nav class="tutorial">
  <h2>Usage tutorial</h2>
  <ul class="tips">
   <li>Hover over robot's left arm for him to greet you!</li>
   <li>Click and hold on bot's body for him to change color</li>
   <li>Hover over bot's legs for him to make a tap dance</li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <div class="robots">
  <div class="android"> 
   <label for="recolor">
   <input type="checkbox" id="recolor">
   <div class="head"> 
    <div class="eyes"> 
     <div class="left_eye"></div> 
     <div class="right_eye"></div>
    </div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="upper_body"> 
    <div class="left_arm"></div> 
    <div class="torso"></div> 
       <div class="right_arm"></div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="lower_body"> 
    <div class="left_leg"></div> 
    <div class="right_leg"></div> 
   </div>  
  </label>  
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have another problem, and that is that you're rotating an element (leg, arm) on `hover`, which can make the element to shake uncontrollably. You can solve that by not having the target of the rotation be the one who activates the rotation, as this video explains: https://youtu.be/8kK-cA99SA0?t=946

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're selecting `#recolor:checked > .torso`, which means any `.torso` that's a direct child of a checked #recolor. That would mean something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="recolor"><div class="torso"></div></input>
```

But that's not your structure, and it's also invalid (`input` can't have children). You have the input, then right next to it, you have a `.head`, then an `.upper_body` and a `.torso` inside of it.

Your selector should be: `#recolor:checked ~ .upper_body > .torso`.

That means any `.torso` that's a direct child (`>`) of an `.upper_body` that's a sibling (`~`) of the checked input.

In this case you have to use `~` instead of `+` because `.upper_body` is a sibling of the input, but it's not right next to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution(OMG, it works!) and the explanation! To think i've been banging my head on this problem for the last two days in the very first week when i started learning to code...
Maybe you can direct me to the resource which can give more insight into multi-layered selectors, like the one you provided? MDN, W3 and CSS tricks all have good explanations, but only for the simple, "single-staged" selectors, like A+B, A>B.
However, when i need to select an element which is inside a couple of other elements, and also have some ":property" attached, i get completely lost.

Comment: @Kekuy I can't think of something right from the top of my head. Just google for "css complex selectors" and you'll find a lot.
Once you have a good understanding of the combinators (descendant " ", child ">", adjacent "+", and sibling "~") then you can do a lot just by chaining them.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
https://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors/

Good luck!

Comment: Okay, got it! At least now i know what to look for. Didn't know this phenomenum has its own name(should have guessed though, hehe). Once again, thanks for your help!